# Flutter: remove duplicated items when filtering ListView

Tags: flutter

I'm working on ListView filtering like this.

[image]

Le't say you type **tsi**. Then the result is:

[image]

which is correct. And if you clear the search input box, the default/original list should be displayed. Instead, there will be duplicated items. Weird.
[image]

Here's the filtering code:

```
  onSearchTextChanged(String input) async {
    List<ParkingItem> dummySearchList = List<ParkingItem>();
    dummySearchList.addAll(_parkingList);

    if (input.isNotEmpty){
      List<ParkingItem> dummy = List<ParkingItem>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((item){
        if (item.location.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())){
          dummy.add(item);
        }
      });

      setState((){
        _parkingList.clear();
        _parkingList.addAll(dummy);
      });
      return;
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _parkingList.clear();
        _parkingList.addAll(backup);
      });
    }
  }
```

And this is [the full code](https://gist.github.com/anta40/5120eea7b04cf4139b597484a7c9032f). What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that `dummySearchList` and the other `dummy` list, seems a bit confusing to me. I would suggest having two lists in the state of your widget. One containing all the items, basically the source of your `ParkingItem`s, and one for the items you want to display.

I've typed this out a bit in dartpad, hopefully this might help you.

```
List<ParkingItem> _allItems; 
List<ParkingItem> _displayedItems; 

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  _allItems = []; // TODO: fetch all items first
  _displayedItems = _allItems; // initially, display all items
}

onSearchTextChanged(String input) async {
  if(input.isNotEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      // set displayed items as a filtered set of allItems, by using `where`
      _displayedItems = _allItems
        .where((ParkingItem item) => item.location.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase()))
        .toList(); // turn the Iterable back into a List
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      // no search field input, display all items
      _displayedItems = _allItems;
    });
  }  
}
```

Comment: this is the approach I use as well

Comment: Yes this is a cleaner approach than mine. After I modified my code accordingly, now it works fine :)